# A script to turn on focus assist for specific duration?

Tags: windows, script, windows-11, focus

I am looking for a script/application for Task Scheduler on my **Windows 11** to turn on focus assist for specific duration (50 mins for example).

I have Power Automate & Task Scheduler on my Windows if this helps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: While not a solution, you can still [find some programmatic clues here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477041/toggling-focus-assist-mode-in-win-10-programmatically)